# How can I prevent \newgeometry from affecting bottom margin when changing the side margins?

Tags: margins, geometry

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\newgeometry{left=10mm,right=10mm}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

For some reason this changes the position of the page number. I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: The page number will be in the 2 centimeter bottom margin, unless you add `includefoot` in the options to `geometry`

Comment: I have added `includefoot` but it has no effect.

Comment: What are you using `\newgeometry` for? If just for accommodating a wider table it's the wrong way. In any case you have to specify also top and bottom.

Comment: I’m sorry, I have misinterpreted what you said. It works fine now, thanks.

Comment: Regarding your question: Yes, I only use it to broaden the figure plus caption. The figure fills the whole page vertically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you specify a new geometry, old values are not retained, so `geometry` uses its standard method, which is of dividing the blank vertical space in a 2:3 ratio between top and bottom after applying the default text height.

Specify the missing parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\newgeometry{left=10mm,right=10mm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

However, this is the wrong method for accommodating a wide object in a figure. Use `changepage` and its `adjustwidth` environment, which doesn't require forcing a page break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{-1.5cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had an `includeheadfoot` in the preamble, but not in the re-definition. It works now.

Comment: +1 for letting me know about `changepage` that doesn't force a pagebreak. Saved me a lot of work.