# Changing some options in \newgeometry while retaining all others by default

Tags: geometry, key-value

I have a document whose preamble says something in this style:

`\RequirePackage[a=3,b=7]{geometry}`

Later in the document I want to temporarily change one parameter, i.e., in pseudocode:

`\newgeometry{keep all other options the same,b=8}`

If I'm understanding correctly about the behavior I see in in practice, if I simply do `\newgeometry{b=8}`, then a will also be changed to its default value, rather than being preserved at 3. Once I saw that the package seemed to behave this way, I thought that the solution would be something like this:

```
\newcommand{\genericgeometryoptions}{a=3}
\RequirePackage[\genericgeometryoptions,b=7]{geometry}
...
\newgeometry{\genericgeometryoptions,b=8}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I get an error from the keyval package when I do the newgeometry macro (not when I initially invoke the package).

I'm trying to avoid having the generic options repeatedly hard-coded in lots of places in my document. Is there a nice way to do this? Am I misunderstanding something about `geometry` or `keyval`?

My question seems similar to this one: [How can I prevent \newgeometry from affecting bottom margin when changing the side margins?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214488/how-can-i-prevent-newgeometry-from-affecting-bottom-margin-when-changing-the-si) However, the accepted answer there simply shows an example in which every non-changing generic parameter is hard-coded twice in the same document. I'm looking for a solution that avoids the need to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `\expandafter\newgeometry\expandafter{\genericgeometryoptions,b=8}` (as a work-around).

Comment: Why do you use \newgeometry and not simply \geometry{b=8}?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer maybe the `\newgeometry` call is mid document?

Comment: If there is no additional `\geometry` call in the preamble but all the options are set via the package options, you could fetch those and forward them to `\newgeometry` with your new keys trailing.

Answer (score 1):

This implements the idea of my comment: Pick up the options given directly to the package, and adding to that list. Caveat: There are options only usable in the preamble (changing the paper size for instance), and those options might result in warnings.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[margin=5cm,a4paper]{geometry}

\newcommand\addtogeometry[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \newgeometry
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    {\csname opt@geometry.sty\endcsname,#1}%
  }

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\blindduck

\clearpage
\addtogeometry{left=8cm}
\blindduck
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```